# How do I write a bash script to pass random files from all sublevels of a directory into an executable one by one?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, random

I'm trying to feed random files from my iTunes Library into mpv, to shuffle my music without iTunes. Initially I tried to pass all the files into mpv using '**' and use mpv's '--shuffle' option, but mpv cannot take that many arguments. Instead, I want to generate the list of files in my own script and pass random elements from it into mpv.

Here is my code:

```
RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)

FILES=(~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/**/**/*)

while [ 1 ]
do
    # Get random song
    nextsong=${FILES[$RANDOM % ${#FILES[@]} ]}

    # Play song
    mpv $nextsong --audio-display=no
done
```

When I run this, something is wrong with the list of files, mpv tries to play incomplete bits of filepaths.

Comment: Looks good, try `nextsong=${FILES[$((RANDOM % ${#FILES[@]}))]}` to insure bash isn't choking on your math inside the `FILES[ ... ]`. Also, no need to seed `RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)` (I would remove it)

Comment: You need to quote `"$nextsong"` to prevent spaces from being word-split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of this, might work for you:

```
while read i
    do mpv "$i" --audio-display=no
done < <(find ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/ -type f| perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle(<STDIN>);')
```

Notice that you may have to add more filtering to the find command in order to make sure you only find appropriate files.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work mostly fine except it detaches control from mpv, so I'm unable to control mpv using the keyboard. Is this a simple fix?

Comment: Use an fd other than standard input for the loop. `while read -u 3 i` and `done 3< <(...)`, etc. Also if you have `shuf` you can probably replace the perl with it.

Comment: @jaxuru Hmmm.. As far as I can see there is no difference between the invocation in my shell scripting and that in the question. Could you control mpv with the keyboard with the shell scripting in the question?

Comment: @CodeReaper The difference is in the loss of stdin.

Comment: Last question, sorry (if SO's format is that I should open a new question let me know, I haven't used SO often). When I close the terminal window that I've run this script in, the mpv process continues and I have to stop the music with `killall mpv` . Alternatives?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed this by adding `|| break` after the mpv call.